# Exception has occurred: OSError [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected

Tags: python, sockets, file-transfer, pyautogui

I am trying to transfer files from client to server. But because of the error i don't receive any files.

this is my server.py file but i get this error when I'm about to receive a file from the client.

```py
import socket
import pyautogui
from pyautogui import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0',4321))
s.listen(5)

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()


while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connecting from {address} has been established")

    msg = clientsocket.recv(1024)
    print(msg.decode("utf-8"))

    file_name = 'recieved file.py'
    file = open(file_name, 'wb')
    file_data = s.recv(1024)
    file.write(file_data)
    file.close()
    pyautogui.alert("File recieved successfully!")
```

this is my client.py below. this doesn't get an error though.

```py
import socket
import pyautogui
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('192.168.0.108',4321))

while True:
    confirm_send = pyautogui.confirm("Do you want to start file transfer?")
    if confirm_send == 'OK':

        file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        file_name = os.path.basename(file)

        open_file = (file, 'rb')        

        with open(file) as in_file:
            file_data = in_file.read()
            s.send(file_data)

        pyautogui.alert("File Transferred succefully!!")
```

this is my error for server.py

```
Exception has occurred: OSError
[WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
  File "D:\Workspace\Code\Cloud Storage\server.py", line 25, in <module>
    file_data = s.recv(1024)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your port is not available.  Have you tried a port in the range 49152–65535?